# read the scipy.beta distribution parameters from a scipy.stats._continuous_distns.beta_gen object

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

Having an instance of the beta object, how do I get back the parameters a and b?

There are properties a and b, but it seems they mean something else as I expected:

```
>>> import scipy
>>> scipy.__version__
'0.19.1'
>>> from scipy import stats
>>> my_beta = stats.beta(a=1, b=5)
>>> my_beta.a, my_beta.b
(0.0, 1.0)
```

Is there a way to get the parameters of the distribution? I could always fit a huge rvs sample but that seems silly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a "frozen" distribution with a call such as `my_beta = stats.beta(a=1, b=5)`, the positional and keyword arguments are saved as the attributes `args` and `kwds`, respectively, on the returned object.  So in your case, you can access those values in the dictionary `my_beta.kwds`:

```
In [10]: from scipy import stats

In [11]: my_beta = stats.beta(a=1, b=5)

In [12]: my_beta.kwds
Out[12]: {'a': 1, 'b': 5}
```

The attributes `my_beta.a` and `my_beta.b` are, as you guessed, something different.  They define the end points of the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of the probability distribution:

```
In [13]: my_beta.a
Out[13]: 0.0

In [14]: my_beta.b
Out[14]: 1.0
```

Comment: excellent, thank you! I was looking at the args parameter, but missed the kwds :)

Comment: Note: if distribution is initialised by positional args like `stats.beta(1, 5)` then `my_beta.kwds` is an empty dict `{}`.  Obviously best practice is to not rely on positional args, but worth flagging.